# What is wrong with my mysql foreign key constraints?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, database-normalization

I am working on a personal project and for the first time ever in my life i'm actually trying to make a database that is normalized (at least to the first thee levels of normalization).  Here are the table's involved in my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `reoccurrences` (
  `name` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(31) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `amount` float(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `action` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `frequency` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`username`),
  KEY `fk_reoccurrences_user` (`username`),
  KEY `fk_reoccurrences_action` (`action`),
  KEY `fk_reoccurrences_frequency` (`frequency`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reoccurrences_action` FOREIGN KEY (`action`) REFERENCES `actions` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reoccurrences_frequency` FOREIGN KEY (`frequency`) REFERENCES `frequencies` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reoccurrences_user` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `reoccurrence` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(31) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `day` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reoccurrence`,`username`,`day`),
  KEY `fk_days_reoccurrence2` (`username`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_days_reoccurrence` FOREIGN KEY (`reoccurrence`) REFERENCES `reoccurrences` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_days_reoccurrence2` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `reoccurrences` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Note, the main problem (I believe) is between these two tables.  There are several other related tables but if i start to list them this post would get very long.  If you want to see the full data structure you can view my project on github here: https://github.com/dallascaley/finance (and i appologize for the profanity/lack of common sense in my github readme, it wasn't intended for public viewing)

The problem happens when i start to add data to these tables.  Here is the data i have:

```
reoccurrences:

name, username, amount, action, frequency
Pay , dallas  , 2500  , credit, bi-weekly
Rent, dallas  , 1400  , debit , monthly

days:

reoccurrence, username, day
Rent        , dallas  , 1
```

Ignore the fact that I don't have a day, or several days listed for Pay.  For some reason when the table is in this state, I can not delete the Pay record from the reoccurrence table.  When i run this:

```
DELETE FROM reoccurrences WHERE `name` = 'Pay' AND `username` = 'dallas';
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`days`, CONSTRAINT `fk_days_reoccurrence2` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `reoccurrences` (`username`))
```

How could I change my table structure to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to fix your constraints in table `days` to use the composite key from `reoccurrences`:

```
CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `reoccurrence` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(31) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `day` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reoccurrence`,`username`,`day`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_days_reoccurrence` FOREIGN KEY (`reoccurrence`,`username`) REFERENCES `reoccurrences` (`name`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see I changed `fk_days_reoccurrence` to a compose key and completely dropped `fk_days_reoccurrence2`, both the key and foreign key references.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct.  I can't believe in my decade of software development that i've never worked at a company that enforced proper data structure (besides HauteLook, but they didn't let me near the database)

Comment: I don't use MySQL much, but the original foreign key constraints from your `days` table to your `reoccurrence` were not good.  They each indicated a 1 to many relation ship between `reoccurrence` and `days` on their respective columns `name(1)->reoccurrence(n)` and `username(1)->username(n)`, but the table `reoccurrence` didn't enforce the 1 instance of either `name` or `username`.  So when you tried deleting from `reoccurrence` the referential constraint on `username` kicked in preventing the deletion since `days` referenced `username` `dallas`, even though there were 2 instances of `dallas`.